# The quest for a more natural distance function $d(x,A)$

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, metric-spaces, definition

In Carothers' Real Analysis, the **distance of a point $x$ from a set $A$** is defined as
$$d(x,A) := \inf\{d(x,a): a\in A\}$$
While this distance enjoys some nice properties, I think it is a little unnatural in the following sense:
It is not necessarily true that $d(x,A) > 0$ when $x\notin A$. For example, $d(x,\Bbb Q) = 0$ for any $x\in \Bbb R$.

Can we find a distance function that satisfies:

1. $d(x,A) > 0 \Longleftrightarrow x\notin A$
2. $d(x,A) = 0 \Longleftrightarrow x\in A$

That seems like a more natural choice! The nice properties that the current definition of $d$ has are:
A. $d(x,A) = 0 \Longleftrightarrow x\in \bar A$.
B. $|d(x,A) - d(y,A)| \le d(x,y)$.

Thanks! Looking forward to insightful discussions on this.

Comment: If you want the distance to be a *continuous* function of $x$ (which is also a nice property) then necessarily $d(x,\Bbb Q) = 0$ for all $x \in \Bbb R$.

Comment: Discrete metric satisfies the two properties.

Comment: $|d(x,A) - d(y,A)| \le d(x,y)$ also implies that $d(x,A) = 0$ for $x\in \overline A$. You'll have to specify which properties you want in order to make it a “natural“ metric.

Comment: That's true! I only want the first two properties and continuity of $f$ - but it seems we can't have those things together, sadly.

Comment: Well, there are reasons to call something a *distance* other than for defining a metric. For instace, $\inf_{y\in A}d(x,y)$ may be called distance because it makes sense to call distance of a point from a region the least distance of the point from a point in the region.

Comment: *it seems we can't have those things together* --- Note also that if the distance function satisfied the property you want, then no essentially new "defined construct" would be made, since all the distance function does would be to provide an alternate way of stating the membership relation $x \in A.$

Comment: @Dave L. Renfro it still would provide additional information since the size of $d$ would indicate how far away a point is from the given set

Comment: @a_student: Good point!

Comment: So you consider it "intuitive" and "natural" for a point $x$ to be closer to some points in the set $A$ than it is to the set $A$ itself? I think you need to get some better intuitions.

Comment: @DaveL.Renfro However, after a second thought: you probably would want to have the property $d(x,A) \leq d(x,A / B)$. Now if you also require that $d(x,\{y\}) = \delta(x,y)$ for some metric $\delta$, I think it comes down to the discrete metric and your intuition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $(X, d)$ be the metric space and $A \subset X$. If you require that
$$ \tag{*}
 \forall x, y \in X: |d(x,A) - d(y,A)| \le d(x,y)
$$
then $d(\cdot, A): X \to \Bbb R$ is a continuous function. If, in addition, $d(x ,A) = 0$ for $x \in A$ then it follows that $d(x, A) = 0$ also for $x \in \overline A$. This shows that
$$
d(x,A) = 0 \iff x\in A
$$
cannot be satisfied together with $(*)$ (unless $A = \overline A$, of course).

Comment: I think you have misinterpreted my question! Sorry for the confusion, I have edited my question to distinguish between (1,2) and (A,B). I want (1,2). (A,B) come along with the current definition, that's all I was saying!

Comment: @strawberry-sunshine: You said in a comment that you want the function to be continuous. In that case the above argument still shows that this is not compatible with properties 1 and 2. There are many discontinuous functions with that property of course, such as $d(x, A) = 0$ if $x \in A$ and $d(x, A) = 1$ otherwise. I think you have to state more precisely in your question what properties (in addition to 1 and 2) you are looking for.